# Spread files out in the workspace in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to save time as I open a lot of files all day with vscode and have a decent screen real estate.  I always want to see the sets of files I open next to each other.  Is there a way of opening a set of files but not have them tabbed, but open auto-arranged so I can see the contents of all of them at the same time?

Comment: You want to open a bunch of files in vscode at once and they should show up in the editor split side by side?

Comment: Yes, although small files could be tiled as well.  It would be good to have as many files open to view as possible logically based on the file length ideally.